# What is the correct configuration for network time sync in ubuntu 17.04+?

Tags: networking, network-manager, laptop, systemd, time

I am on a dual boot laptop running Ubuntu 17.04 and Windows 7. Booting into windows sets RTC to local time, breaking the system clock in ubuntu.

I do not want to change the RTC configuration on ubuntu or windows; I want ubuntu to sync time to the network as soon as there is a network connection. This used to be done with ntpdate (which is now deprecated) and as far as I can see, the current configuration for ubuntu systems uses systemd-timesyncd. This is not working, and so far I have been unable to force timesyncd to sync time.

/etc/systemd/timesyncd.conf is set to use pool.ntp.org:

```
[Time]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
NTP=0.pool.ntp.org                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
FallbackNTP=1.pool.ntp.org 2.pool.ntp.org 3.pool.ntp.org
```

However, systemd status shows that timesyncd is not capable of connecting to pool.ntp.org:

```
● systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.d
           └─disable-with-time-daemon.conf
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-08-07 10:13:38 PDT; 1min 44s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-timesyncd.service(8)
 Main PID: 986 (systemd-timesyn)
   Status: "Idle."
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-timesyncd.service
           └─986 /lib/systemd/systemd-timesyncd

Aug 07 10:13:37 rachael systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Aug 07 10:13:38 rachael systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Aug 07 10:14:48 rachael systemd-timesyncd[986]: Timed out waiting for reply from 204.2.134.163:123 (0.pool.ntp.org).
Aug 07 10:14:59 rachael systemd-timesyncd[986]: Timed out waiting for reply from 91.224.149.41:123 (0.pool.ntp.org).
Aug 07 10:15:09 rachael systemd-timesyncd[986]: Timed out waiting for reply from 103.242.70.5:123 (0.pool.ntp.org).
Aug 07 10:15:19 rachael systemd-timesyncd[986]: Timed out waiting for reply from 178.62.16.103:123 (0.pool.ntp.org).
```

This is probably due to the fact that timesyncd depends on networkd, but since ubuntu uses network-manager to handle its connections, networkd is disabled:

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
```

Incidentally, timedated is also disabled (no idea if this is relevant):

```
● systemd-timedated.service - Time & Date Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timedated.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:systemd-timedated.service(8)
           man:localtime(5)
           http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/timedated
```

Consequently, timedatectl lists ntp sync as disabled, independent of the content of the config file:

```
      Local time: Mon 2017-08-07 10:27:48 PDT                                                                                                                                                                                               
  Universal time: Mon 2017-08-07 17:27:48 UTC                                                                                                                                                                                               
        RTC time: Mon 2017-08-07 17:27:48                                                                                                                                                                                                   
       Time zone: America/Los_Angeles (PDT, -0700)                                                                                                                                                                                          
 Network time on: yes                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
NTP synchronized: no                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Trying to enable ntp sync on timesyncd by hand has no effect. i.e.:

```
# timedatectl set-ntp true
```

does nothing.

How is network time synchronization supposed to work in newer ubuntu systems?

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/943920/need-help-installing-ubuntu-desktop-17-04-alongside-windows-10?noredirect=1#comment1499199_943920

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, yup, I am aware that you can tell windows to treat RTC as UTC time with 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation] “RealTimeIsUniversal”=dword:00000001 but I do not want to mess with RTC in either windows or linux; I want to get network  time sync to work :)

Comment: Oh so you have to manually edit the Windows registry? I always hated doing that.

Comment: timedatectl is the tool. Cant tell what you are asking exactly. If you want ntp use a different ntp server.

Comment: Ah I have no idea if there's an easier way, that's what Google suggested... Assuming RTC to be on local time is insane anyway, so who knows. Windows is weird!

Comment: @bodhi.zazen how? I've played with it for two days, and it does nothing and I refuse to set the time by hand, that's what we have machines for.

Comment: https://linoxide.com/ubuntu-how-to/change-timezone-ntp-sync-ubuntu-16-04/

Comment: @Terrance that's what I would have done before the age of systemd, but I assume that my use case is not that strange and that there must be a proper way to get simple standard behaviour to work with Ubuntu's current default config of systemd+network-manager.

Comment: @Terrance: Didn't work. ntp was not installed, and installing and running the service has no effect whatsoever, even though timedatctl now says "NTP synchronized: yes".

Comment: @Manoj Sawai: restarting services also seems to have no effect at all.

Comment: Forget that.  It was on my older work computer.  That's why I removed my old comments.  I actually found on my home system it is configured correctly and working and synced up just fine.

Comment: @ManojSawai OK, I am stupid; turns out changing the netowrk fixed it with a simple `systemctl restart timedated`. Thank you all for your comments, and sorry for wasting everybody's time.